# How to pass a literal value to a kedro node?

Tags: python, kedro

I've got a function

```py
def do_something(input_data, column: int):

    # Do something with one column of the data
```

Now I need to create a kedro node, but I can't do `node(do_something, ["input_data", 1], "output")`. How can I put the constant value (1) into the node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach would be to pass the data via params. Add `column_number: 1` to the parameters.yaml file, and then your node definition would look like `node(do_something ["input_data", "params:column_number"], "output")`.

If you need to reuse the same function in many nodes, changing the column, then it will not work easily. Instead you can use [partial](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial), something like `node(partial(do_something, column=1), "input_data", "output"])`

Comment: It's advised to use `update_wrapper` for more informative log messages since the `partial` object does not have `__name__` or `__doc__` attributes by default. `p1 = partial(do_something, column=1); node(update_wrapper(p1, do_something))`