# kedro nodes input accept kwargs?

Tags: kedro

https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/kedro.pipeline.node.Node.html#kedro.pipeline.node.Node.inputs

I have a function

def function(**kwargs):
return

How can I pass variable to it as a node inputs?

```
**inputs**
Return node inputs as a list, in the order required to bind them properly to the node’s function. If the node’s function contains kwargs, then kwarg inputs are sorted alphabetically (for python 3.5 deterministic behavior).
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one work around for this problem by using decorator factory function. Using python3 in this example.

You can import **wraps** decorator from **funtools** package

```
    from functools import wraps
```

```
    def deco_factory_df_params(
        *deco_args,
        **deco_kwargs,
    ) -> Callable:
        def deco_fn_df_params(
                func: Callable,
        ) -> Callable:

            @wraps(func)
            def add_df_params(*args, **kwargs):
                kwargs = {**kwargs, **deco_kwargs}
                return func(*args, *deco_args, **kwargs)

            return add_df_params

        return deco_fn_df_params
```

and passing keyword parameters of your choice to this decoration factory function while calling the node in kedro pipeline.
For example.

```
    node(
        func=deco_factory_df_params(
            parameter1="value1",
            parameter2="value2",
            parameter3="value3",
        )(your_function_name),
        inputs="data_input1",
        outputs=None,
        name="name_of_node",
    ),
```

your node(function) definition may look like as below

```
    def your_function_name(
        df_input: pyspark.sql.DataFrame,
        parameter1: str,
        parameter2: str,
        parameter3: str,
        **kwargs,  # this is important to be here to avoid error
    ) -> None:
        function_code_here
        
        return None
```

@mediumnok: I hope this works for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the `node` function available inside of `kedro.pipeline`. You can use a dictionary to pass in kwargs to the function.

```
from kedro.pipeline input Pipeline, node

def my_kwarg_fun(**kwargs):
    print(kwargs)

def create_pipeline():
    return Pipeline([
        node(
            my_kwarg_fun,
            inputs={
                "my_kwarg": "example_my_kwarg"
            },
            outputs=None
        )
    ])
```

```
# This should print
# {'example_my_kwarg': ...}
```

Comment: I get this error instead
File "c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\kedro\runner\runner.py", line 89, in run
    "DataCatalog".format(unsatisfied)
ValueError: Pipeline input(s) {'example_my_kwarg'} not found in the DataCatalog

Comment: So it works if "example_my_kwargs" is a dataframe. Seems nodes always evaluate the string as an variable, if I actually need to pass in a string as variable it doesn't work, I have to define it in parameters.yml and use params:key to reference instead.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58875820/how-to-pass-a-literal-value-to-a-node

Answer (score 0):

Use the key when sending your parameters.

For example, if you want to send `PARAMERTOPASS`, use a splittable key with a prefix such as `input_`:

```
node(
    func=function_to_send_parameter,
    inputs={
         "input_PARAMETERTOPASS": "data_catalog_item",
          ...
    },
     output="another_data_catalog_item",
   ),
...
```

Then, in your function, extract `STRINGTOPASS` from the pefix `input_`:

```
def function_to_send_parameter(**kwargs):

    for key, value in kwargs.items():
        if key.startswith("input_"):
            df = value
            passed_parameter = key.split("input_")[1]
            print("This is the received parameter: ", passed_parameter)
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is an information about nodes with **kwargs in docs:
https://kedro.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nodes_and_pipelines/nodes.html#kwargs-only-node-functions

```
def reporting(**kwargs):
    result = []
    for name, data in kwargs.items():
        res = example_report(name, data)
        result.append(res)
    return combined_report(result)
```

additionally there is an information how to handle *args (mapping):

```
from kedro.pipeline import node


+mapping = lambda x: {k: k for k in x}
+
 uk_reporting_node = node(
     reporting,
-    inputs={"uk_input1": "uk_input1", "uk_input2": "uk_input2", ...},
+    inputs=mapping(["uk_input1", "uk_input2", ...]),
     outputs="uk",
 )
```